# iPhone - Anyway to get iPhone's Email App Inside Your Own App?

Tags: iphone, email

Has anyone every embeded the iPhone's Email program inside your own App?

Let me try and simplify that.  Tap Tap Revenge allows you to "Challenge A Friend".  When you choose to do so they open the standard iPhone email program (if they mimicked it, it looks damn good), within the application with pre-populated data.  All you have to do is select a friend from your contacts and press send.  You never leave the Tap Tap Revenge App.

Any ideas how this is done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the `MessageUI.framework` into your project, and inside your header file you need to set the delegate:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
    MFMailComposeViewController *email;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MFMailComposeViewController *email;
```

Once you do that, you have a few delegate methods inside your implementation file you need to include (You should check to see the result, but I am trying to keep as little code as needed):

```
@synthesize email;

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [email dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Wherever you want to use this, you need to initialize and set it up like this:

```
email = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
email.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// Subject
[email setSubject:@"Testing"];

// Optional Attachments
NSData *artwork = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"albumart.png"]);
[email addAttachmentData:artwork mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"albumart.png"];

// Body
[email setMessageBody:@"This is the body"];

// Present it
[self presentModalViewController:email animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, this will point me in the right direction and get me started!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Further to Garett's great response, should you get the warning:

'MFMailComposeViewController' may not respond to '-setMessageBody:'

add isHTML: so the complete line reads like:

[mail setMessageBody:@"This is the body" isHTML:NO];

Answer (score 0):

There is two answers for that. For applications that should support iPhone OS prior 3.0 the only way to go is to build a custom message composer. Or you may want to have a look at the component built by Joe Hewitt who wrote the Facebook iPhone app.

http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTMessageController.h

With iPhone SDK 3.0 you are able to use the Mail message composer UI straight out if the box using the `MessageUI.framework` as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

[messagecomposer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010161-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) is the way to go! mails and sms inside the app, run from iOS 3.1. need sdk 4